# Cannot connect to Cassandra in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect to a remote cassandra cluster in my spark shell using the Spark-cassandra connector. But its throwing some unusual errors.

I do the usual thing as mentioned on the github page of spark-cassandra connector

1. Run the shell

   $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-s_2.11

2. import cassandra connector

   import com.datastax.spark.connector._
   import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
   Everything works fine upto this point
   But when i try to create an rdd

   val rdd=sc.cassandraTable("test","user")

it throws this exception

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.apply(CassandraConnectorConf.scala:257)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:189)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.SparkContextFunctions.cassandraTable$default$3(SparkContextFunctions.scala:52)
  ... 53 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Spark version-2.3.1
connector version = 2.0.0

Comment: how did you
 define the sc and conf?

Comment: you need to set few cassandra properties with in your spark configureations, hope [this](http://khodeprasad.github.io/blog/read-the-data-from-cassandra-tables-using-apache-spark/) will help you...

Comment: i have set it using --conf property : spark.cassandra.connection.host=ipaddress

Answer (score 4):

For Spark version 2.3.1 you must use Spark Connector version >= 2.3.0 - current version is 2.3.2:

```
spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.2 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=<IP>
```